# how to rmmod at reboot?

Tags: drivers, reboot, systemd

I have a driver that will not start properly unless I use rmmod before reboot.  Unfortunately it is a network driver, so I loose access to my machine once I remove it.  I am wondering what the best way to do this is.  Maybe systemd?

Comment: Are you able to both rmmod and then insmod on startup to get the device working properly?

Comment: No, the machine crashes if I do that.